# What are the general instructions to add a new fragment that uses a new screen and has its own layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to figure out how to create fragments that have their own layout files and take up the whole screen, as opposed to adding them to the activity's layout.

For instance, in my activity there is a button which should call a RecyclerView Fragment that takes up the whole screen, let the user pick an item, and then return to the activity. All the examples I'm finding though use transactions to add or replace on the activity's layout. How do I make fragments that are inflated from their own layout files and call them from the activity?

And sorry, I'm sure there's a better way to ask but I'm just going through docs and vids trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A few line difference between Fragment and Activity:

An Activity is an application component that provides a screen, with which users can interact in order to do something. More details: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Whereas a Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html